# What is the limit of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\ln\left(n^2+5\right)+\sqrt{n^2+1}}{n^2\sqrt[3]{n+1}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

How can I calculate the limit of this series?
$$
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
\frac{\ln\left(n^2+5\right)+\sqrt{n^2+1}}{n^2\sqrt[3]{n+1}}
$$
Could you show me the steps to follow? Thank you.

Comment: Almost surely you can't.

Comment: I have no idea what the sum is. It does converge, by limit comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{n^{4/3}}$.

Comment: I don't think that there is any hope to get a closed form expression. The numerical value $6.2189805825513451755642278266354666237977335001610$ does not match anything in inverse symbolic calculators.